# Compile error: End If without block If

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently running the below loop to pull out information from another spreadsheet, but keep getting the following error message **Compile error: End If without block If**, at

```
ElseIf cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Physical"
```

What could be causing it and how do I remediate it? My code below:

```
' Loop though cells in column A on main.xlsm
For r = 1 To m

    ' Can we find the value in column A
    Set cel = wshS.Columns(3).Find(What:=wshT.Cells(r, 1).Value, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        If cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Yes" Then wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Virtual"
        ElseIf cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Physical"
        Else: End If
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: `1` Change "ElseIf" in "ElseIf cel.Offset(0, 8).Value" to "If" `2` Delete "Else: End If"

Comment: Just a note to others who may have trouble with this error: If you use the Single-line syntax (in @SiddharthRout's answer) nested within another If statement, and you put an End If for the inside and outside statements, you will get this compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further to my comments above, change your code to

```
If Not cel Is Nothing Then
    If cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Yes" Then wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Virtual"
    If cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Physical"
End If
```

or to this

```
If Not cel Is Nothing Then
    If cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Yes" Then
        wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Virtual"
    ElseIf cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then
        wshT.Cells(r, 14).Value = "Physical"
    End If
End If
```

For the syntax of `IF/EndIf`, see the below

```
'~~> Multiple-line syntax:
If condition [ Then ]
    [ statements ]
[ ElseIf elseifcondition [ Then ]
    [ elseifstatements ] ]
[ Else
    [ elsestatements ] ]
End If

'~~> Single-line syntax:
If Condition Then [ statements ] [ Else [ elsestatements ] ]
```