# End If without block If error

Tags: vba, excel

I Wrote this code. I dont understand why I got error : End If without block If

```
Sub mytest()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim k As Integer
s = 0

With Worksheets("mysheet")
.Range("B28:B75").Select

For i = 28 To 75
        If Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        s = s + 1
        End If
Next i

.Range("A28:A75").Select

For j = 28 To 75

    If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then Cells(i, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLightDown
    Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

Next j

p = 75 - s
For k = 1 To s
    Cells(s + k, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(18, 0, 0)
Next k

End With
```

The End If clause wasnt omitted. I dont understand why I got error

Comment: Try to move statement after `Then`on new line

Comment: Note that your error is not `Block If without End If` but `End If without block If`. You don't have an missing `End If`, you have too much ;) (see answer from Macro man below  or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22580564/5350831) ) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move statements after `Then` on new line. IMHO VBA expects single line statement if you use it with code after then, so next line with code without `end if` throws this error. I also recomends you to read more about VBA [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) for better range and cell specification.

but for your error use something like this

```
Sub mytest()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim k As Integer
s = 0

With Worksheets("mysheet")
.Range("B28:B75").Select

For i = 28 To 75
        If Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
        Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        s = s + 1
        End If
Next i

.Range("A28:A75").Select

For j = 28 To 75

    If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then
    Cells(i, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlPatternLightDown
    Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If

Next j

p = 75 - s
For k = 1 To s
    Cells(s + k, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(18, 0, 0)
Next k

End With
```

Answer (score 4):

If you write an If statement on a single line this:

```
If Foo = Bar Then FooBar()
```

You don't need to use an `End If` because the action is executed on the same line and so the end of the statement is *implied* (The compiler knows anything after `Then` on the same line is conditional, so you don't need to tell it where your conditional code ends)

If you place the action on a separate line:

```
If Foo = Bar Then
    FooBar()
End If
```

Then you have to *explicitly* tell the compiler where the conditional code ends by using an `End If` because there is no other way for it to know.